# Append row to kendo grid with each response

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have the datasource :

```
var dataSource1 = new kendo.data.DataSource({

        transport: {
            read: {
                url: ..dataUrl,
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json"
            },
            parameterMap: function () {
                return JSON.stringify({ field : value });
            }
        },
        schema: {
            data: function (response) {
                return [response];
            }
        }
  });
```

and binding grid using:

```
 function bindGrid(){
 $('#grid').kendoGrid({

        dataSource: dataSource1,
        columns: [
            {
                field: "Id",
                title: "Account Id",
                width: "10%",
                template: function (item) {
                    return item.Id !== null ? kendo.toString(item.Id) : "null";
                }
            },
            {
                field: "status",
                title: "Status",
                width: "20%",
                template: function (item) {
                    return item.status !== null ? kendo.toString(item.status) : "null";
                }
            }
        ]
    });
  }
```

and I'm calling the method bindGrid() in a loop.

Becouse I have to bind the result of each response from the same dataSource to the same grid.
When I'm doing this, it has only one result(one row is binded). The result is  overwriting each time the call executes.

How can I bind the grid by appending the results.

Comment: The dataSource request doesn't fetchs all rows? I'm afraid you're misusing the dataSource for remote data. Can you show your *loop* ?

Comment: The remote call return a response with respect to the call. But Im caling data source url for multiple times and have to bind each of the responses to the grid. The loop is:
var count = selectedIds.count;
for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                result[i] = createDataSorce(selectedIds[i]);
                bindGrid();
            }